# Can't get BPM property from file in TagLib

Tags: c++, file, c++11, taglib

There is code:

```
TagLib::FileRef f(file);
PropertyMap properties = f.tag()->properties();

cout << properties.toString() << endl;
```

It's return all avalible properties except BPM

```
ARTIST=artist
COMMENT=text                             
DATE=year
GENRE=genre
TITLE=Song name
```

What's wrong?

Comment: note that the `taglib` tag is not specifically for the library `TagLib` you are using, though that seems to be the common useage of the tag...

Comment: BPM (beats per minute) is not a "tagged property" of an audio file. That's the reason it is not being returned. You simply cannot do this using TagLib. You need to find some other library for this purpose. Just make a web search using "bpm estimation in c++", you will surely find some.